# Django uploading MediaFiles to S3

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Im trying to upload MediaFiles to S3 with django on EC2

im using django storages, here is my settings:

```
S3_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media/'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
MEDIA_URL = os.path.join(S3_URL, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
```

my custom storage class :

```
class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
    location = settings.MEDIAFILES_LOCATION
```

when i try to upload files, im getting an error 500 wihout any error in nginx logs.

I got the same config for static files and it works fine.

Everything is working fine on localhost.

Comment: Which python version do you use?

Comment: im using python 3.4.3

Answer (score 0):

My configuration is quite similar :

```
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = os.environ.get('DJANGO_AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN', AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME)

MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'pop.storage.MediaStorage'
```

And the class:

```
class MediaStorage(S3BotoStorage):
  location = getattr(settings, 'MEDIAFILES_LOCATION', '')
```

Maybe it can help..

With which plugin do you upload your file ? do you use filer ?
What does the network return when you upload a file ?

Comment: Im not using any plugin, just got a FileField or ImageField and let django do the rest, it works fine if you setup a media directory in local, all tuto i have read didnt mention you need extra plugin, do i need it to works with S3 ? network giving me an error 500

Comment: I am not sure about extra plugins, it just that filer is very effective (easy to implement) and clean.

So you are not reaching the server. Are the keys correct, no cross domain errors etc ?

Comment: there is the exact error : FileUploader.js:479POST https://alpha.akt.io/api/v1/artworks/ 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
when i try to upload file directly via django shell like in the docs http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html everythink works fine my file is uploaded on S3, can the probleme be from nginx ?

Comment: Man.. it comes from your js file. Start by looking at it first.

Comment: I dont think so, when im doing curl request im getting error 500 to without any error in nginx log, and this files is from javascript library